# Blackberry turn over Application

Tags: blackberry

is it possible to turn over Application of Blackberry bold 9000 to blackberry 8520 ?
Any one have idea?

EDIT::
i want to switch Application

- BB bold 9000 OS-->5.0.0.411  to
- BB curve 8520 OS --> 4.6.0..
  it is possible or not...

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the requirements of your application. Unless you are using any OS or hardware specific functionality, turning over your application from one phone to another should not be an issue. By OS specific I mean functionality that is available in, for instance,  OS v5.0 and not available in v4.0.

Basically, your question is a bit vague for us to provide a 'Yes' or a 'No'

Comment: If you have the source code you could always just compile it against 4.6 and see if they used any spesific 5.0 API's andif they did remove/change them